# Objective-c - Stop centralizing the user location when the map updates its self

Tags: ios

I created a simple application with the MapKit framework. When it starts, the user location is zoomed in and shown. But when I zoom out and scroll around the map, it automatically centralizes it self to the user location again after a couple of seconds. How can I stop this?

In the m-file:

```
#import "APPNAMEViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@synthesize mapview;

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation     {
    mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = location;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:NO];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     mapview = [[MKMapView alloc]
           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                    44,
                                    self.mapview.bounds.size.width,
                                    self.mapview.bounds.size.height)
           ];
     mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
     mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
     mapview.delegate = self;
     [mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:NO];

     [self.view addSubview:mapview];
}
```

Please help me :)

Best regards
Michal

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];` in  `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation`

Answer (score 0):

```
[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO]; //Changes the currently visible region and optionally animates the change.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove : [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:NO];

This makes the map center on current location.